# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Minimal Web API with Ocelot as API gateway redirects to downstream service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ocelot

I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0 Minimal Web API with Ocelot as API gateway. I've uploaded it to my production server and use this configuration in `ocelot.json` config file:

```
{
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://api.mySite.com"
    },
    "Routes": [
        {
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/sync/info",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/info",
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "sync.mySite.com",
                    "Port": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that when I send a request to the `https://api.mySite.com/sync/info` URL, it redirects to `https://sync.mySite.com/info` in my browser and displays the result.

First question: is this true? How to prevent to redirection when request my API via API gateway (I've also removed the line `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` from `program.cs` class of my API gateway project and re-published to production server, but still facing the same result)?

Second question: if I changed `downstreamScheme` to `https`, I am facing an http 502 (bad gateway) status code, while when I request downstream service directly via https, it works correctly. Where is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Redirect" Do you mean the URL in browser has changed? But ocelot should "rewrite" which doesn't change browser URL.

Comment: For the first part of your question, Yes i do. For second part, i don't know this behave is normal or not, but i think it should not redirects to original url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question,

You should check **app.UseHttpsRedirection()** in downStream host, not in API Gateway. Because whether you send HTTP request or not, this will turn it into HTTPS.

Second question,

As an estimation (because there isn't enough info)

you changed downStreamScheme to HTTPS, have u changed the port from 80 to 443 ?

Comment: For the first answer, basically, the app.UseHttpsRedirection() exists in downstream service, but i don't know if i remove it, it works on https request or not??        For the second part, no i didn't changed port. Should i changed it to 443?

Comment: Yes, my second problem was solved!!! I've changed port 80 to 443 when i use https for downstream service and it works! Thanks        But the first Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It works!!

**First problem :**
Change port number to 443 when use https for your downstream service!

**Second problem :**
Use app.UseHttpsRedirection() in your api gateWay project and re-publish to your server. **Remember, Clear your browser cache** when you call your endPoint!!!